# The background color of the dropdown list in my navigation wont display properly

Tags: html, css

I've got a nested list which I intend to use as a drop-down list in my navigation, but the background color for the drop-down list isn't displaying properly. It's just showing as an underline for the parent list item, not as a background color for all of the nested list items.
I'm not sure why it's not working since I set the background color style for the nested list items specifically.

Here is my code:
HTML - http://pastebin.com/W5w8HWyj
CSS - http://pastebin.com/Wi4j3L63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#nav ul li ul{
background-color: #606060;
}
```

is it like what u want? [SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gqmkyktx/1/)

Comment: Doesn't work for me even if I add it at the end of the .css file :/ Even in the fiddle it doesn't look like it works. It doesn't extend the entire way, only to the edge of the words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for this with #nav ul li:hover li{background:#B6B6B6;border-bottom:1px solid #000;width:150px; padding-left:10px;} set.